# Trying to count the amounts of entrances of a certain type by separately

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called `posts` that it has a field called `forum_type_id`.

And another table called `forum` that it has a field called `forum_type` and an `id`.

the id's of the forum table represent the type that its using to relation with the `forum_type_id` from the `posts` table

Now, in my DB.

- In posts I have 3  entries with the `forum_type_id = 2` (representing the type 2 of my forum table that is "Questions").
- 2 entries with the `forum_type_id = 1` (representing the type 1 of my forum table that is "General")

I'm trying to make a query that get the amounts of every "type" by separately

I try something like this .

```
  SELECT DISTINCT
    (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM posts WHERE posts.forum_type_id = '1') AS generalCount,forum.id
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM posts WHERE posts.forum_type_id = '2') AS questionsCount, forum.id
FROM forum;
```

I expect to get for this example

generalCount = 2;

questionsCount = 3;

but it make a addition and returns me just 1 line with the 2 numbers added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about `group by`?

```
SELECT p.forum_type_id, COUNT(*)
FROM posts p
GROUP BY p.forum_type_id;
```

You can get the names from the forums table if you like:

```
SELECT f.?, COUNT(*)  -- use the column with the name you want
FROM posts p JOIN
     forums f
     ON p.forum_type_id = f.forum_type_id
GROUP BY p.?;
```

You can pivot this to put the values in columns rather than rows, but that may not be necessary.

Comment: For the OP's particular case, just add `WHERE forum_type_id IN (1, 2)` +1 though

Answer (score 1):

You can try using conditional aggregation

```
SELECT 
    count(case when posts.forum_type_id = '1' then 1 end) AS generalCount
,
    count(case when posts.forum_type_id = '2' then 1 end) AS questionsCount
,
    forum.id
FROM forum
group by forum.id
```